# Pivoting a two-column DataFrame into value counts by date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that is indexed by a default range. It has two columns: "date" and "type".

```
         date  type
0  2019-01-01     A
1  2019-01-02     C
2  2019-01-03     A
3  2019-01-01     B
4  2019-01-01     A
5  2019-01-02     B
6  2019-01-02     B
7  2019-01-03     C
8  2019-01-03     A
9  2019-01-01     B
```

My desired end result is a DataFrame like this:

```
      date  A  B  C
2019-01-01  2  2  0
2019-01-02  0  2  1
2019-01-03  2  0  1
```

I'm decently close with this:

```py
df.pivot_table(index='date', columns='type', aggfunc={'type': 'count'}, fill_value=0)
```

But it produces this strange result that I can't figure out how to interpret:

```
               type
      type  A  B  C
      date
2019-01-01  2  2  0
2019-01-02  0  2  1
2019-01-03  2  0  1
```

Any clues on what I'm missing? It seems that this should be rather straightforward.

Comment: try with df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(1)

Comment: what you did, with an indexing step at the end: `df.pivot_table(index='date', columns='type', aggfunc={'type': 'count'}, fill_value=0)['type']`

Comment: @cs95 That gets me close but it still has that leftmost type over date.

Comment: Just add a `'reset_index()` call then?

Comment: Using `rename_axis` should give your expected output: `df.pivot_table(index='date', columns='type', values='type',  aggfunc='size', fill_value=0).rename_axis(None, axis='columns').reset_index()`

Comment: Thanks @Erfan! That's exactly what I need. I just didn't need `reset_index()` as I want the date to be the final index. Please add an answer so I can accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) to remove the `name` object of the column index axis:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='date', 
                    columns='type', 
                    values='type', 
                    aggfunc='size', 
                    fill_value=0).rename_axis(None, axis='columns')

            A  B  C
date               
2019-01-01  2  2  0
2019-01-02  0  2  1
2019-01-03  2  0  1
```

Which would be same as:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='date', 
                    columns='type', 
                    values='type', 
                    aggfunc='size', 
                    fill_value=0)

df.columns.name = None
```